# Fade out on Ajax submit

Tags: ajax, timeout

I have this ajax submit script. It does submit properly and pops up the thank you message, but it does not fade out in 3.2 seconds. The goal is to have the message "Thank you for updating." pop up for a few seconds each time a user clicks on an update button (#tracking_submit).

```
$('#tracking_submit').click(function(){
$.ajax({
url: "php/tracking.php",
    type:'POST',
    data: dataString,
    success: function(){
           $('#tracking_message').replaceWith("Thank you for updating.");
       $('#tracking_message').delay(3000).fadeOut(300);
        }                   
    });
    return false;   
});
```

Answer (score 0):

I solved this issue this way

```
$('#tracking_submit').click(function(){
    $.ajax({
        url: "php/tracking.php",
        type:'POST',
        data: dataString,
        success: function(){
            $('#tracking_message').html("Thank you for updating.").fadeIn('slow');              
            setTimeout(function(){$('#tracking_message').fadeOut('slow');},2000);
        }                   
    });

    return false;   

});
```

Answer (score 0):

Try using this:

`setTimeout(function() { $('#foo').fadeOut(); }, 5000);`

`.delay()` doesn't play well with anything else since the timer keeps ticking and a `.dequeue()` is executed when it's up...regardless of if you cleared the queue and added a whole new one.

It's better to use `setTimeout()` directly. `setTimeout()` is a native javascript function.